# Incorrect syntax near '1' sql

Tags: sql

I am trying to understand why I am getting the following error when running the query:

> Incorrect syntax near '1'

```
Select  * 
From    _datatable 
WHERE   Dateadded BETWEEN DATE_SUB(GETDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND GETDATE()
```

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: The `INTERVAL` syntax and `DATE_SUB()` looks like MySQL, but `GETDATE()` is a SQL Server function, I believe.

Comment: ^ Yea, you want `CURDATE()` instead of `GETDATE()`

Comment: And the convention of "Incorrect syntax near..." looks like a SQL Server error, not MySQL.

Comment: I can not use CURDATE() or NOW (). my web based query execution console does not support it.

Comment: @99problems You need to verify for us what database you use. It would appear based on the error message, and the lack of CURDATE(),NOW(), that your database is MS SQL Server. It has its own set of date functions, which don't include those or `DATE_SUB()`.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx

Comment: I can't help but snicker at the fact that your username is "99problems" and your problem was "1".

Comment: @99problems cause you have a SQL Server, not a MYSQL Server. Thus, `DATE_SUB` should be replaced with `DATEADD` (http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_dateadd.asp), a negative value and proper syntax.

Comment: Ugh... every time someone links to w3schools a puppy dies. [Try the SQL Server documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx).

Comment: Voting to close the question until the OP edits it to add a tag indicated which DB he's actually using (if he even knows... seems like he may be making a bad assumption about the tool he's using).

Answer (score 3):

I see mixed syntax from two different database engines here: SQL Server and MySQL.

Here's the SQL Server way:

```
SELECT * 
FROM _datatable 
WHERE Dateadded BETWEEN DATEADD(month, -1, current_timestamp) AND current_timestamp
```

And in MySQL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM _datatable 
WHERE Dateadded BETWEEN DATE_ADD(current_timestamp, INTERVAL - 1 MONTH) AND current_timestamp
```

Comment: Your MySql query says "Incorrect syntax near 'MONTH'."

and SQL "Invalid column name 'dateadded'."

Comment: What's the actual column name, then? `Dateadded` is what you posted.